# How can I fix FileNotFoundException exception if the file is already there?

Tags: java, tomcat, teamcity, keytool, catalina

I created a .jks file with this command

```
keytool -genkey -alias TeamCity -keyalg RSA -keystore KeyStoreTC.jks -keysize 2048
```

after that I moved the .jsk file to my directory but I am receiving this error

> Failed to load keystore type JKS with path
>   file:///C:/integrationProces/TeamCityDeploy/KeyStoreTC.jks due to
>   C:\integrationProces\TeamCityDeploy\KeyStoreTC.jks (The system cannot
>   find the path specified) java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\integrationProces\TeamCityDeploy\KeyStoreTC.jks (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)

The file is in that directory but I have no idea why the java.io.FileNotFoundException exception

I am using catalina(tomcat) and TeamCity and I am trying to enable https and this is my configuration in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8099" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
   SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
   keystoreFile="file:///C:/integrationProces/TeamCityDeploy/KeyStoreTC.jks"
   keystorePass="mypass" />
```

I also commented this line of code in server.xml as a recommendation that I found in a forum

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Could it be that `integrationProces` is misspelled? Are you copy-pasting the exact path?

Comment: Try remove the `file:///` as it need native-filesystem path. Also try to check if tomcat has permission to read the file.

Comment: Might wanna check what user teamcity is running as to be sure that user has permission to view files created by catalina

Comment: @Kon you were right, I copy-paste the path but seems that by mistake later I deleted one letter. Thanks for the help